# jQuery implode/join strings (elements) with a custom character (hyphen)

Tags: jquery

i have a selection of (2) elements, selected by this:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").children("td").children("span");
```

when i do this:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").children("td").children("span").text();
```

the texts in the spans (say a and b) are concatenated together (to ab), and thats almost what i want

But now i want to concatenate them by inserting a hyphen (-) in between (to a - b)
I've tried this, but that doesn't work:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").children("td").children("span").join(" - ");
```

Comment: join is used with array elements.you can not directly use it with a variable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use $.map:

```
$.map(
  $(this).parents("tr:first").children("td").children("span"), 
  function(element) {
      return $(element).text()
  })
  .join(" - ");
```

Comment: or this construction: `$(this).parents("tr:first").children("td").children("span").map(function(i, element){return $(element).text()}).get().join(" - ")`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this...

```
var m = [];
$(this).parents("tr:first").children("td").children("span").each(function(index, element)  {m.push(element.text());});  
return m.join(" - ");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this)
    .parents('tr:first')
    .children('td')
    .children('span')
    .append('-') // append hyphen to each span
    .text();
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this  may feel a little heavy just not as complex.

```
$(this).parents("tr:first td span:eq(0)").text() + " - " + $(this).parents("tr:first td span:eq(1)").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

modifying @Gajus answer, this will be the shortest and probably the easiest:

```
$(this)
.parents('tr:first')
.children('td')
.children('span')
.clone()   //making sure the html is not modifying
.append('-')   // append hyphen to each span
.text();
```

or,

```
$('.your-selector here')
.clone()   //making sure the html is not modifying
.append(',')   // append hyphen to each span
.text();
```